# how to develop android image distorstion

Tags: android, image, distortion

how to develop the image distortion in android , i.e: in adobe Photoshop there is one default control (forword warp tool) which is used to image distortion and i need to make this control function by android coding..

is any body have made any kind of this application which will able to make the image distortion by android,,

for refarance i shows one image on which by Photoshop's  forword warp tool's help the image distortion done,, i need to do like that control functionality by android coding ....

Thanks in advance.....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to implement your own image distortion class which can manipulate the image matrix.. Maybe you should search the web maybe you find sth.

something like this:

```
distort(int[][][3] image, double[][][3] matrix){
    for(int i =0; i < imagelength; i++){
        for(int j =0; j< imagewidth; j++){
            image[i][j][0] = (int) (image[i][j][0] * matrix[i][j][0]);
            image[i][j][1] = (int) (image[i][j][1] * matrix[i][j][1]);
            image[i][j][2] = (int) (image[i][j][2] * matrix[i][j][2]);
        }
    }
return image;
}
```

pixel i,j will be distorted if

```
matrix[i][j][0] != 1
matrix[i][j][1] != 1
matrix[i][j][2] != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Find image distorstion libaries written in java and try to implement them on android.